# What is the JsonPath syntax used by Json.NET?

Tags: json, json.net, jsonpath

I'm trying to select some nodes with Json.NET `SelectTokens` it doesn't seem to support the same syntax the [original jsonpath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/index.html#e2) supports. Given this input:

```
{
    "a": [
        {
            "id": 1
        }
    ],
    "b": [
        {
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "c": {
                "id": 4
            }
        }
    ],
    "d": [
        {
            "id": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

I want the ids of all top level objects inside `a`and `b` only, but not of inner objects. Using goessner's parser I'm able to do it with: `$.[a,b].*.id`, it returns `[1, 2, 3]`.

Json.NET doesn't seem to support neither the comma or the *. How can this be achieved with Json.NET and are there any reference for what is supported by Json.NET jpath selectors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following path will work with Json.NET 10.0.2:

```
var path = @"$.['a','b'][*].id";
```

This path seems consistent with the [original JsonPATH article](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/), which states:

> JSONPath expressions can use the dot–notation
>
> `$.store.book[0].title`
>
> or the bracket–notation
>
> `$['store']['book'][0]['title']`

Specifically:

- Names inside brackets are shown to be quoted.  Presumably doing so distinguishes between indices and numeric names.
- Array indices are always shown to be in brackets rather than between periods.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ifypcA).

(Honestly, the original article is somewhat vague and allows for variation in implementation.  For instance, exactly what does *script expression, using the underlying script engine* mean?)

Comment: Why does everyone refer to it as Json.NET when it's Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: `Newtonsoft.Json` is the namespace.  Json.NET is the product name, see https://www.newtonsoft.com/json.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer a hundred times. Even a fiddler example! Bravo.