# How does one interpolate a variable name in a dynamic object by passing it as a value to a key in a json configuration file (C#)?

Tags: c#, json

MRE ('cause licensing issues)
I have a dynamic object in C# (which is essentially used to deserialize a json string):
`dynamic jsonObj = JsonConvert.Deserialize(<theJsonString>);`
Then, I am taking in a configuration file all the keys of the json that need to be set. Yeah, I know it is always better to set the Json manually, but its the requirement of this project that the keys to be set and their respective values are passed in using a REST API.: `dynamic confKeys = <DeserializedObject>`
An upside is that the keys in the `confKeys` object are in their full access path. So, for a key of the type `{["keyOuter":{"keyInner":"valueInner"}]}`, the `confKeys` will have the string "jsonObj[0].keyOuter.keyInner" as a key.
This is the conceptual representation of what I want to do: `configuration[0].name as a variable being accessed = configuration[0].value as another variable being accessed`.

---

MRE Structure of config file (the outer one, i.e. the one that holds the keys and their values to be inserted):

```json
{[
  "jsonObj[0].keyOuter.keyInner": "someValue",
  "jsonObj[2].keyLaLa": "someValueLaLa"
]}
```

---

In essence, my configuration file holds pointers to another json file's objects' keys...
PS: Is there any way to eliminate the restriction on the user of referring to the outermost object as `jsonObj`?

---

EDIT: Clarification to the best of my abilities:
**Before**:
a sample json file:

```json
{
  "someOuterKey.someInnerKey.someEvenMoreInnerKey": "someValue"
}
```

another related sample json file:

```json
{
  "someOuterKey": {
    "someInnerKey": {
      "someEvenMoreInnerKey": "someCurrentValue"
    }
  }
}
```

**After**:
a sample json file:

```json
{
  "someOuterKey.someInnerKey.someEvenMoreInnerKey": "someValue"
}
```

another related sample json file:

```json
{
  "someOuterKey": {
    "someInnerKey": {
      "someEvenMoreInnerKey": "someValue"
    }
  }
}
```

---

Currently have been able to deserialize both the jsons (using `dynamic objects`) but can't find a way to convert the keys in json1 to variables which access json2.

---

Comment: I find it very hard to understand what you are trying to achieve with you current wording in this post. Please add: sample input AND output (both current and desired result), and what you have tried so far

Comment: You should have a look at [json path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855083/what-is-the-jsonpath-syntax-used-by-json-net).

Comment: Can you please explain _"variables which access json2."_. You want to modify values in the second object?

Comment: yes, precisely @GuruStron

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK dynamic deserialization in Newtonsoft Json.NET internally uses `JToken`'s, so you can use them directly. For example using JSON Path syntax via `SelectToken(s)`:

```cs
var js1 = """
{
    "someOuterKey.someInnerKey.someEvenMoreInnerKey": "someValue"
}
""";
var js2 = """
{
    "someOuterKey": {
        "someInnerKey": {
            "someEvenMoreInnerKey": "someCurrentValue"
        }
    }
}
""";
var o1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(js1);
var o2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(js2);
foreach (var kvp in o1)
{
    var value = kvp.Value.Value<string>();
    var selectToken = o2.SelectToken(kvp.Key);
    if (selectToken is not null)
    {
        selectToken.Replace(kvp.Value);
    }
}

var serializeObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o2); // {"someOuterKey":{"someInnerKey":{"someEvenMoreInnerKey":"someValue"}}}
```

**UPD**

Array sample:

```cs
var js1 = """
{
    "jsonObj[1].keyLaLa": "someValueLaLa"
}
""";
var js2 = """
{
    "jsonObj": [
        {},
        {"keyLaLa" : "olddValue"}
    ]
}
""";
var o1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(js1);
var o2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(js2);
foreach (var kvp in o1)
{
    var selectToken = o2.SelectToken(kvp.Key);
    if (selectToken is not null)
    {
        selectToken.Replace(kvp.Value);
    }
}

var serializeObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o2); // {"jsonObj":[{},{"keyLaLa":"someValueLaLa"}]}
```

Comment: It is not always `var value = kvp.Value.Value<string>();`... it can also be `var value = kvp.Value.Value.Value[0].Value<string>();`

Comment: @justanotherguy you will need to adapt your code for all potential cases. As you can see (in the `foreach`) the `JObject` (and `JArray`) allows iterate the json contents in any way you need. You can even write some [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/queryinglinqtojson.htm)

Comment: @justanotherguy For example you can do ` o1.Descendants().OfType<JValue>()` and then analyze paths of values, etc.

Comment: So as it turns out, all I really needed was "Dynamitey"

Comment: @justanotherguy After rereading your comments I still wonder what you could not do with the suggested approach. JSON path (and `SelectToken`) support arrays, so everything mentioned in OP should be handled. I will check again later, but can you please show example what have you meant by `kvp.Value.Value.Value[0].Value<string>()`, because right now I have a theory that we have misunderstood each other? –

Comment: No, actually as it turns out, Dynamitey does not work :( I didn't test it well enough. I think the solution has something to do with flattening and unflattening the json structure

Comment: @justanotherguy added an array sample.

Comment: Erm.. at the risk of you getting mad at me, Dynamitey actually worked.. I was just calling the wrong Method (InvokeSet instead of InvokeSetChain).

Comment: but sure, I'll try your way when I get time and the upcoming release of the project is out of the way. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: @justanotherguy _"at the risk of you getting mad at me"_ - no risk here, you are free to pick the best solution which works for you =) And my pleasure, good luck with the project!